# XmlTextReader move to start

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

This is my requirement
i need to deserialize an object and then i need to do some xml parsing(i know how it sounds)
So here is my code

```
XmlTextReader myFileReader = new XmlTextReader(path); 
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType)); 
MyType par = serializer.Deserialize(myFileReader)  as MyType;

XElement qListenerParXml = XElement.Load(qListenerPar);
```

When i try to load the reader again i'm getting exception because the reader cursor is at the end.
My question is how do i return it back to the beginning?

Comment: `new XmlTextReader` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. You should use `XmlReader.Create` instead. You can then create the reader against a `MemoryStream` or some other kind of stream which can be repositioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`XmlTextReader` is forward-only, you cannot rewind the cursor on the data.

You could do this by going over the data again with a new instance of `XmlTextReader`, or by loading it as an `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @UshaP - or load it for random access as `XmlDocument`. With the `XmlReader` classes you get better perf but no random access.